# What type of grammar in "True Say"?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

> Man: I ain't going down. There's too many things down there out to get
>   me.
>
> Man 2: True say. Bare police, crazy gangsters and fucked-up monsters
>   down there.

If I were in Man 2, I would say **Its true**.
But Man 2 says different & sounds very stylish, I want to know exact type of grammar is used?

This dialogue is from "Attack the Block (2011)".

Comment: What is the source of this dialogue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's slang. Inner city London slang, or to be precise, a white middle class comedian writing inner city London slang for a film script. The movie [transcript](http://movietranscript.blogspot.co.uk/2015/11/2011-attack-block-english-transcript.html) includes quite a few of these "partial" sentences. In particular "True say" means "It's true what you say" or "Is it true what you say?"

As a learner you should not usually try to emulate slang speech as it changes very fast, and can be very local. It dates very rapidly, and may not be understood out of its neighbourhood.